# Continuum between arithmetic mean, AGM, and geometric mean

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, means

**NOTE:** I am aware of [this possible duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126099/interpolation-between-arithmetic-mean-and-geometric-mean), but my question is slightly different as it also involves arithmetic-geometric mean.

The arithmetic mean  of two numbers is defined as:
$$\text{am}(a,b) = \frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}$$
For example, $\text{am}(3,12) = 7.5$. Similarly, geometric mean of two numbers is defined as:
$$\text{gm}(a,b) = \sqrt{ab}$$

So $\text{gm}(3,12)=6$. The [arithmetic-geometric mean](http://arithmeticgeometricmean.blogspot.com/) is a mean "between" these two, calculated as follows:
$$
a_{0}=a,g_{0}=b\\
a_{n+1}=\text{am}(a_{n},g_{n})\\
g_{n+1}=\text{gm}(a_{n},g_{n})\\
\text{agm}(a,b)=\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\;\;(a_n)
$$

For instance, $\text{agm}(3,12) \approx 8.7407$.
Note that $\text{gm}(a,b)\leq \text{agm}(a,b)\leq \text{am}(a,b)$.

**My question:** I need to define a general mean $M(a,b,c)$ for $0\leq c \leq 1$ that satifies these properties:
$$
M(a,b,0) = \text{am}(a,b)\\
M(a,b,0.5) = \text{agm}(a,b)\\
M(a,b,1) = \text{gm}(a,b)
$$
[Power mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) is not what I'm looking for, as $PM_{0.5}\;(a,b) \neq \text{agm}(a,b)$ (e.g. $PM_{0.5}\;(3,12) = 8.7464... \neq 8.7407...$).

Comment: Can you give an example that the power mean is different?

Comment: For given $a, b$ you could simply define $M(a, b, c)$ as the (quadratic) interpolation polynomial with the required values at $c=0, 0.5, 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Standard quadratic interpolation, as suggested by  @Martin-R

\begin{align} 
M(a,b,t)&=
(2t-1)(t-1)\operatorname{AM}(a,b)
\\
&-4t(t-1)\operatorname{AGM}(a,b)
\\
&+t(2t-1)\operatorname{GM}(a,b)
.
\end{align}

Or in expanded form,

\begin{align} 
M(a,b,t)&=
 (\sqrt a+\sqrt b)^2\,t^2
 -(\tfrac32\,a+\tfrac32\,b+\sqrt{ab})\,t
 +\tfrac12\,a+\tfrac12\,b
 \\
 &+\frac{\pi t(1-t)}
 {\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2\,x^2}\right)^{-1} \, dx }
.
\end{align}

---

**Edit**

At the second thought, I must admit that
such interpolation is a bad choice for general $a,b\ge0$.
It's ok for just switching between the three values $t=0,\tfrac12,1$ and works
relatively reasonable for some ranges of $a,b$, but it could
as bad as returning negative output, for example,
$M(1000000,1,0.9)\approx-2081$, so it needs a serious treatment.

Comment: This is a good answer, but doesn't work for $a=0$ or near 0, so you need to perform a check for those.

Comment: @Nirvana: a check ? What is a check ? This is calculus, not numerical analysis.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean make M a piecewise function which has a condition for the case I mentioned.

Comment: @Nirvana: I don't see a reason for this function to be piecewise. What does "near" mean ?

Answer (score 2):

The geometric mean can be turned to an arithmetic one by a nonlinear mapping,

$$\sqrt{ab}=f^{-1}\left(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2\right)$$ where $f(x):=\log(x)$ is the logarithm.

Hence a way to construct "intermediate" means is by using a function intermediate between the identity and the logarithm. You could obtain yours by solving the functional equation

$$2f(\text{agm}(a,b))=f(a)+f(b).$$

By homogeneity, it should be enough to solve

$$2f(\text{agm}(a,1))=f(a)+f(1).$$

Of course solving this equation seems arduous. I guess that you can solve it numerically and tabulate $f$. Then you'll have a generalization of the arithmetico-geometric mean for $n$ arguments.

Whether you can find a natural "interpolation" between these three means seems even less tractable.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is a sort of generalization by bisection method.

For instance, with this generalization
$M(a,b,0.25)$ would be given by the following iteration:

$$a_0=a~,~b_0=b$$
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}~,~b_{n+1}=AGM(a_n,b_
n)$$

Note that since the arithmetic-harmonic mean is just the geometric mean, this would imply that within this generalization:

The harmonic mean would be $M(a,b,2)$.

And the geometric harmonic mean would be $M(a,b,1.5)$.

---

It may be useful to instead align the definition of this generalized mean to line up with the power means, so that
$$M(a,b,1)=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$M(a, b, 0.5)=AGM(a,b)$$
$$M(a,b,0)=\sqrt{ab}$$
$$M(a,b,-0.5)=GHM(a,b)$$
$$M(a,b,-1)=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$

Then these would have the nice property that
$$M(a,b,n)=\frac{1}{M(\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},-n)}$$